# PHP intdiv, why would there be +2 before division?

Tags: php, math

The following code has intdiv, however there is a +2 after the dividen, before the divisor, why?

```
       $sitem_qty=0;
       foreach($order_items as $item_id => $item) {
            if ($item['product_id']==$S_ID) {
                $sitem_qty += intval($item['qty']);
            }
        }
        //number of boxes in this order
        $shipping_boxes = intdiv($sitem_qty+2,3); // what does the +2 do and what does it equal? Why do this?
        //remaining capacity
        $capacity_remaining = $shipping_boxes*5;
```

What does the +2 do??? intdiv($sitem_qty+2,3)

Comment: Either the author of the code just literally adds `2` to the `$sitem_qty` or it is a trick of some sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a quick test, based on the information you gave and the variable names, I believe they put +2 to make it iterate in 3's (maybe 3 items per box?)
I may be wrong, but here is the code I used to make that determination.

```
<?php  
$s1 = 1; $s2 = 2; $s3 = 3; $s4 = 4; $s5 = 5;  
$s6 = 6; $s7 = 7; $s8 = 8; $s9 = 9; $s10 = 10;

echo intdiv($s1+2,3)."<br>"; echo intdiv($s2+2,3)."<br>"; 
echo intdiv($s3+2,3)."<br>"; echo intdiv($s4+2,3)."<br>";  
echo intdiv($s5+2,3)."<br>"; echo intdiv($s6+2,3)."<br>"; 
echo intdiv($s7+2,3)."<br>"; echo intdiv($s8+2,3)."<br>"; 
echo intdiv($s9+2,3)."<br>"; echo intdiv($s10+2,3)."<br>"; 
?>
```

and here is the output I got for comparison.
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4

Comment: Yeah that is the answer! 3 items per box. How does +2 make it iterate in 3's ?

Comment: removing the +2 shows this. "0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3"
I think the +2 is just to ensure that there is at least a 3 to divide 3 from so it's always at least 1 box

the bare minimum 1 item would create 0 boxes without the +2
if you wanted to cut down to 2 items per box you would make it +1, and higher would be +3

Comment: Okay sure, that makes sense as there always has to be a box. Thanks man!

Comment: best of luck :)